# Angular 16 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, angular, angular16

I am trying to create a new project using Angular 16. I need it to connect to MySQL. I know how to do this just using a simple Express server, but I'm pretty new to Angular. While there are a number of tutorials out there about Angular and MySQL, those all seem to be for older versions of Angular and from what I understand, the way things are done in version 16+ is quite different than older versions.

What is the most up-to-date way to add MySQL to Angular 16+? More specifically, I mostly need to know what I need to install with npm and where in the project I need to add what?

Info:
When I build the project, I did so with:

```
ng new --directory <folder-name> --routing --standalone --strict --style sass <project-name>
```

Other possibly important information:

```
Angular CLI: 17.0.3
Node: 20.9.0
Package Manager: npm 10.1.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.0.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.0.3
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.3
@angular/cli                    17.0.3
@schematics/angular             17.0.3
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.2.2
zone.js                         0.14.2
```